# How can i search all tables for a specific node value's parent_id?

Tags: php, mysql, database

There are several other posts like this but none which match my specific parameters/needs.

How do i find the `parent_id` associated with one of 50 different outputted query results a user could click on?

Like, if the user clicks on "`Transportation`" I need code that can find the `parent_id` corresponding to the transportation node.

Problem is, my data is structure over multiple tables, so if they click on a link I don't necessarily know which table to search.

Essentially what I want is `SELECT parent_id FROM * WHERE * = communication`

But I can't `*` for parameters such as table name.

So how do I create code to automatically find the `parent_id` of a specific query once the user selects it?

There must be a better option than listing all my `20 tables` in the query parameters?

Should I restructure my data into 1 table?

Comment: could you show us some of the tables? I'm thinking a join might be in order

Comment: is Transportation column name or value?

Answer (score -1):

You have to search each table for the parent_id. If you want shorter codes, you can try this:

```
<?php
$tables = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
while($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables)){
    $queries[] = 'SELECT parent_id FROM `' . $table[0] . '` WHERE method=\'Transportation\'';
}   
$result = mysql_query(implode(' UNION ', $queries));
?>
```

Comment: You should not use query in loop..??